# how do I include quoted HTML in a Tornado Template?

Tags: templates, tornado

I'm using Tornado Templates and one of my fields is a string that has HTML tags quoted in it, e.g.
    <p>Solar power</p>

When I render it into the template, the tags are quoted verbatim instead of treated as tags.
    {{ quoted_html }}
So it looks exactly as above with the p tag visible.

In other templating systems, {{ = foo}} renders foo verbatim, but {{html foo}} treats the tags as tags.

Is there the equivalent in Tornado Templates?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`{% raw foo %}`, in Tornado 2.0+.

If you do that with a lot of expressions in a template, you can add the `{% autoescape None %}` directive to the beginning of the template, after which `{{ foo }}` will not be escaped.